# The type 'COMSVCSLib.ObjectControl' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: .net, web-services, com, vb6, rcw

- I have two VB 6 assemblies (DLLs). ProgramA.dll, and ProgramB.dll, which I need to add as reference in my .NET Web Service (version 2.0).
- I was handed over these two DLLs by different developers.
- One developer gave me simply ProgramA.dll
- The other developer gave me ProgramB.dll, ProgramB.exp, and
  ProgramB.lib
- I simply registered ProgramA.dll using regsvr32 and added its
  reference in my .NET project
- I then added reference of ProgramB.dll
  in my .NET project
- Now when I try to build my .NET Web Service, it is giving me following error:
  The type 'COMSVCSLib.ObjectControl' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced.
  I can see following files in References of .NET application:
  COMSVCSLib
  Interop.COMSVCSLib
  Interop.ProgramA
  Interop.ProgramB

Also, the code is showing problem with ProgramB assembly (for which I had those .exp and .lib files)

What could be the possible reason, or am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: You shouldn't have two different references on COMSVCSLib. What happens if you remove one or the other? Where are these references coming from? Did you add it yourself? PS: .exp and .lib files are useless for a .NET client.

Comment: @Simon - please add this as an answer and I will mark it.. thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't have two different references on COMSVCSLib. You could try to remove one or the other.

PS: .exp and .lib files are useless for a .NET client